# .htaccess to strip subdomain from a dynamic domain/host name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some htaccess which redirects to www.domain.com unless its already on the www or www2 subdomain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www2\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

BUT this current bit of code doesn't strip off any current subdomain already on the host.

So what I'm looking for is some htaccess that will first strip off the subdomain and then add www. or a similar idea.

My other requirement though is that the domain name is dynamic as this same bit of htaccess is used on a number of sites. Which is why in my current bit of code I use the %{HTTP_HOST} variable. But maybe there's another variable that would work better for this case?

Comment: try to look at the php $_SERVER variable outputing it print_r($_SERVER), maybe you can find the one you need, cause htaccess & php uses the same vars

Comment: Hi @Rustam, for the purposes of this, I'd like a pure htaccess solution. (although sure it'd be simple in PHP, or any server side language)

Comment: So you want to remove _all_ subdomains in case it's not starting with `www` or `www2`? eg, `www.foo.bar.example.com` is fine, but `foo.bar.example.com` should redirect to `www.example.com`?

Comment: Hi @ndm, actually all subdomains should redirect, e.g. foo.example.com, foo.bar.example.com and www.foo.bar.example.com should all redirect too www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example try matching for a `www(2).domain.tld` scheme, capture the parts of the host with an additional condition for `HTTP_HOST`, and use it in the rules replacement part, something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www2?\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This should redirect all non `www(2).domain.tld` hosts to `www.domain.tld`.

ps. Make sure sure to use the appropriate [**response status code**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) depending on what you're trying to achieve with these redirects.

Comment: Hi @ndm, thanks for this, however this doesn't appear to work with domains using second-level domain names such as domain.co.uk or doamin.org.uk. Any ideas around this?

Comment: In my case i happen to only need the following supported:
.co.uk
.com
.org
.org.uk
.com.au
.net
.info. 
So i'll try and mod the regex to allow for these.

Comment: Ended up with the following in my .htaccess: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www2?\.([^\.]+\.(com(\.au)?|(recds12\.)?co\.uk|org(\.uk)?|net|info))$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+\.(com(\.au)?|(recds12\.)?co\.uk|org(\.uk)?|net|info))$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]`